# how to compare the value in different size of each Dataframe and returning String

Tags: python, pandas

Assuming that I am going to compare the 5 dataframes which are

```
ID_DocAll ID_Doc1 ID_Doc2 ID_Doc3 ID_Doc4
  10         21     21      10      7
  21         7      10      21
  32                32      54
  54                 7    
   7
```

and see the expected result as

```
ID_DocAll 
10        ID_Doc2, ID_Doc3
21        ID_Doc1, ID_Doc2, ID_Doc3
32        ID_Doc2
54        ID_Doc3
7         ID_Doc1, ID_Doc2, ID_Doc4
```

any suggestion? I have follow this post [Comparing Boolean Values of Pandas Dataframes- Returning String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33905944/comparing-boolean-values-of-pandas-dataframes-returning-string)

but I have problem with the size of the dataframe and cannot resize them even I made it to be equal by filled NaN with 0.

Comment: empty values in input data are missing values or empty strings?

Comment: it is the empty string

Answer (score 0):

Use if empty values in input data are empty strings and `ID_DocAll` column has unique values:

First remove `ID_DocAll` column for processing all another columns by [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), remove rows with empty strings and aggregate `join` per values

```
s = (df.drop('ID_DocAll', axis=1)
       .melt(var_name='ID_DocAll')
       .loc[lambda x: x['value'].ne('')]
       .groupby('value')['ID_DocAll']
       .agg(','.join))

print (s)
value
7.0     ID_Doc1,ID_Doc2,ID_Doc4
10.0            ID_Doc2,ID_Doc3
21.0    ID_Doc1,ID_Doc2,ID_Doc3
32.0                    ID_Doc2
54.0                    ID_Doc3
Name: ID_DocAll, dtype: object
```

And last for change order use [`Series.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reindex.html) (only necessary numeric values in index of `s` and numeric in `ID_DocAll` column):

```
s1 = s.reindex(df['ID_DocAll'])
print (s1)

ID_DocAll
10            ID_Doc2,ID_Doc3
21    ID_Doc1,ID_Doc2,ID_Doc3
32                    ID_Doc2
54                    ID_Doc3
7     ID_Doc1,ID_Doc2,ID_Doc4
Name: ID_DocAll, dtype: object
```